# BlackBerry invalidate speed problem

Tags: blackberry, invalidation

I have custom field with volume slider (just color line),
I want to update slider on trackpad movement, is there some other way
then invoking invalidate? Because this is realy slow for me,
a tried also invalidating only region but whit same result. So is there 
 some way how to repaint part of field without invalidate?

```
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
    if (dx >0) {
        if (value < maxValue) {
            value++;
            invalidate(xPosSlider + value*sliderStep, getHeight()/2 - SLIDER_HEIGHT/2, sliderStep, SLIDER_HEIGHT);                                  
            return true;
        }
    } else if (dx < 0) {
        if (value > 0) {
            value--;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to look is at your own code. Are you doing something time-consuming on the even thread that is preventing the paint operations from occurring in a timely manner? That's the likely problem.

Otherwise, you can try [calling the paint method directly as shown here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/doPaint-issues/td-p/361388). But the best solution is to ensure that your event thread is not tied up doing work that should be done on a separate thread.